# select column from list

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have a `List<string>` where are stored database table column name.

I need to select only this column (where name is stored into list) from a c# linq query.

Is possible?

I Try this code but I don't know how I can place in select:

I try this code

```
items = items.ToList();
            _items.Add(new FieldItem() { FieldName = "field1" });
            _items.Add(new FieldItem() { FieldName = "field2" });
            _items.Add(new FieldItem() { FieldName = "field3" });
            _items.Add(new FieldItem() { FieldName = "field4" });

            _db.Table.Where(a => a.TimeStamp > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)).Select(....);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. Give us what you've tried by now.

Comment: Include sample list, expected output and what you have tried

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include an [mcve].

Comment: I think its a bad decision from @Gilad Green, I agreed it's a low quality post and too bored, but doubt about the duplicate

Comment: Also please explain what Database is it

Comment: What does your `FieldItem` model look like? How are you getting data from your database?

Comment: It is possible but it is not easy. First of you are supplying columns to select dynamically so a typed object is out of the question. I would suggest using a simple query but since EF cannot map to dynamic(as far as I know) you are left only with some tool like Dapper. You can still use your DbContext to supply the SqlConnection to Dapper.

Comment: I get data from database with dbContext. FieldItem have only one string field (called FieldName).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use reflection. 
In string list are stored property name. 
Get a property by name, and get it's value.

In this way get all PropertyInfo for a class:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
```

When property name match, update property value with:

```
property.SetValue(child, parentProperty.GetValue(parent));
```

Isn't an optimized solution, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) via NuGet.

After that put in using in your code:

```
using Dapper;
```

And you're good to go. All you would need to do now is(using the example you have posted):

```
using (YourDbContext _db = new YourDbContext())
{
    return _db.Database.Connection.Query($"SELECT {string.Join(",", _items.Select(if => if.FieldName))} FROM Table WHERE TimeStamp > @TimeStamp;", new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });
}
```

This methods would return IEnumerable which would have all of your fields. The results can be casted into IDictionary where the key is your column name and the value is the actual value.

So for instance, if we were to get the first row in the results with First(), we could access the field values like this:

```
var value = ((IDictionary<string, object>)result.First())["column_name"];
```